Use brush for transform_calculate in interactive altair char
I have an interactive plot in altair/vega where I can select points and I see a pie chart with the ratio of the colors of the selected points.
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

selection = alt.selection_interval(encodings=["x"])

base = (
    alt.Chart(
        pl.DataFrame(
            {
                "x": list(np.random.rand(100)),
                "y": list(np.random.rand(100)),
                "class": list(np.random.choice(["A", "B"], 100)),
            }
        )
    )
    .mark_point(filled=True)
    .encode(
        color=alt.condition(
            selection, alt.Color("class:N"), alt.value("lightgray")
        ),
    )
    .add_params(selection)
)

alt.hconcat(
    base.encode(x="x:Q", y="y:Q"),
    (
        base.transform_filter(selection)
        .mark_arc()
        .encode(theta="count()", color="class:N")
    ),
)

The outcome looks like this:

Now I'd like to add two more charts that show the ratio of selected / unselected points for each color. I.e. one pie chart that is orange / gray and one pie chart that is blue / gray with ratios depending on the number of selected points.
I tried to use the selection like this
    (
        base.mark_arc().encode(
            theta="count()",
            color=alt.condition(
                selection, alt.Color("class:N"), alt.value("gray")
            ),
            row="class:N",
        )
    ),

But it's not what I want:

What's the best way to add the pie charts I want?

There might be an easier way to do this, but the following works:
alt.hconcat(
    base.encode(x="x:Q", y="y:Q"),
    (
        base.mark_arc(theta=4)
        .transform_joinaggregate(class_total='count()', groupby=['class'])
        .transform_filter(selection)
        # Including class_total in the groupby just so that column is not dropped since we need it in the calculate
        .transform_aggregate(count_after_filter='count()', groupby=['class', 'class_total'])
        .transform_calculate(proportion_selected=alt.datum.count_after_filter / alt.datum.class_total)
        .encode(
            # Setting the domain to reflect that we computed a proportion
            theta=alt.Theta('proportion_selected:Q').scale(domain=(0, 1)),
            row='class',
            color='class'
            # tooltip='proportion_selected:Q'
        )
    )
)


Together with your initial chart, this could make for an interesting gallery example if you want to create a PR.
For a grey background, I think you would have to layer with a completely filled in grey chart, similar to this layered histogram here https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interval_selection_map_quakes.html (should just be alt.Chart().mark_arc(color='lightgrey')

I like this, thanks! I'll try to put up a PR to add this as an example. Maybe more generally, is it possible to use the fact that points are brushed as further properties? Something like .transform_calculate(property= brush) and then later potentially as .encode(row="property:N")

@Thomas Interesting, so property here would be a field in the data that indicates whether the points in inside the selection or not? I haven't seen that before but maybe it is possible with the calculate transform. To test it out, you might benefit from using the vega_editor where you can inspect the different intermediate datasets that are created. Another option to achieve similar behavior could be to create two versions of the same chart, one filtered on brush and one on the negated ~brush .

Yeah my thought was that having property available just like any other field of the data would make some things easier. For example, the blue pie could be realized via .transform_filter( get blue).transform_calculate(property=brush).encode(theta="count()", color="property"). I'll check out the editor to see what works. But your example + layering the gray background worked :)
